# If $p,q$ are positive integers, $f$ is a function defined for positive numbers and attains only positive values such that $f(x(f(y))=x^py^q$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> If $p,q$ are positive integers, $f$ is a function defined for positive numbers and attains only positive values such that $f(x(f(y))=x^py^q$ then prove that $p^2=q.$

I am posting one solution below. Looking forward to seeing other solutions, which are more instinctive/intuitive or maybe involve derivative or plain hit and try, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x=\frac1{f(y)}$ in the given equation, we get,$$f(1)=\frac{y^q}{f^p(y)}$$

Putting $y=1$ here, we get, $$f(1)=1\implies f(y)=y^{q/p}$$

Putting this in the given equation, we get $$f(xy^{q/p})=x^py^q=(xy^{q/p})^p$$

We may write this as,$$f(y)=y^p$$

Comparing this with the earlier $f(y)$, we get$$p^2=q$$

Comment: Why is this a separate answer and not part of the question?